# Forwarding ICMP traffic to POX controller is not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, communication, sdn, openflow, pox

i am new in SDN, and i am trying to forward ICMP traffic received by wlan0 interface to a pox controller which is running on a machine on the same network. To do so , i installed openvswitch to rapsberry pi and i send icmp traffic to the wlan0 interface but the device reply as if i had not configured the openvswitch. For forward traffic i added the following line:

```
ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 "table=0,priority=100,icmp,in_port=3,actions=output:CONTROLLER"
```

I had also set the openvswitch to connect to the controller :

```
ovs-vsctl set-controller br0 tcp:192.168.1.100:6653
```

I can see that the controller and my openvswitch are connected, but traffic is not forwarded, so what's going on?

I would appreciate any help.